# テーブルのヘッダーにタイトルとサブタイトルを表示させる方法が分かりません

Tags: swift, swift4

初心者です。質問に足りない情報等あるかもしれませんが、宜しくお願い致します。
テーブルのヘッダータイルの下に、フォントサイズがヘッダータイトルより小さいタブタイトルみたいなものを入れたいのですが、入れ方がよく分かりません。
５つ設定しているヘッダータイトルのうち、すべてでは無く２つほど設定したいです。
お分かりになる方がいらっしゃいましたら、是非ともご教授のほど宜しくお願い致しいます。

環境: swift4, xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

独自にカスタマイズしたヘッダーを使用したい場合は
[tableView(_:titleForHeaderInSection:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614850-tableview) ではなく、[tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614901-tableview) と [UITableViewHeaderFooterView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewheaderfooterview) を使います。

詳しくは、以下のページなどを参考にしてください。

[[Qiita] UITableViewHeaderFooterViewをxibで生成する](https://qiita.com/KikurageChan/items/e1847b54535df393d893)

Comment: 大変参考になりました。リンクまで付けて頂き有難うございました。無事に解決致しました。ご教授頂き有難うございました。

Comment: お役に立てて何よりです。質問が解決しましたら、回答の承認をお願いします。 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: 失礼致しました。回答の承認致しました。ご回答頂き有難うございました